# Switch easily between browser and editor

Tags: gnome, emacs, window-switching

My usual workflow is like that (for instance): My screen is split into two. My editor (Emacs or whatever) for markdown  is on the left, the other  on the right (web browser to view the results of changes I made in editor.)

- Save changes in my editor
- Press Alt-Tab to switch to browser window. I usually have many windows open and it is sometimes taking time to press Alt-Tab several times (I usually miss the window I need.) Then click F5 to refresh my browser.
- Then back to my editor to edit my markdown and recycle above items again if necessary.

I wonder there is a way to shorten the time of doing all the steps above. I am using Gnome. I would like to bind a key for all steps above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using gnome, but you should be able to do what you want by mixing tools `xbindkeys` and `wmctrl`. (The former may have a gui `xbindkey-config` for easier configuration).

`xbindkeys` listens for keyboard events you configure in file `~/.xbindkeysrc`, and will run a command when it sees them.

`wmctrl` talks to conforming window managers and asks them to move, resize, activate windows identified by id or name.

For example this config should activate your emacs when you type <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

```
"wmctrl -a emacs"
  Alt+equal
```

Instead of having two such bindings, you can also use `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname` to find the name of the currently focused window, and then toggle to the other window. `xdotool` can also activate windows, if you have problems with gnome and `wmctrl`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on your window manager, invoke a command from your editor to focus the browser window. If you merely want to open a new tab, all you have to do with Firefox or Chromium/Chrome is run the browser executable with the desired URL. For example, in Emacs, you can type `M-! firefox http://localhost/myfile.md RET`.

If you want to focus an existing window, you can use [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool). You can also make it inject keystrokes in the browser window to trigger the browser's reload command.

```
xdotool search --class Firefox --name 'My web page' windowactivate --sync key F5
```

This assumes that the tab you want is active. Firefox and Chrome have no easy built-in way of switching tabs from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use workspaces, they're exactly what you're looking for!

As you use GNOME, it's very easy to add new workspaces. Think of a workspace as "one desktop".

So you can have specifiv windows open on different workspaces. You can also add keyboard shortcuts to quickly move to a specific workspace. E.g. `SUPER+number` is a often-used combination. (`SUPER` is the Linux name for the "Windows key".) As you use GNOME, you can also just press `SUPER` to open a workspace overview, where you can click one to switch to it. Pretty handy!

Now you just have to decide on where to put your windows. I for myself have a very strict setting:

```
Workspace 1: Browser
Workspace 2: Game
Workspace 3: IDE + Terminals
and so on...
```

So when I want to look into my browser, I always know that I just have to press `SUPER+1` and - boom! - I'm in my browser. Back to programming? `SUPER+3` and start typing.

Comment: Aha! It is a good hint. But I usually want to jump between  two application windows side by side ( covering whole screen), not among workspaces. A